# ASP.NET GridView Update/Overall Query Structure

Tags: c#, asp.net

New Question.
I have this as my gridview and I want to have it so when the page loads the grid view is filled with the database information.

So below is the code for the gridview. and below that is the c# code.

UPDATE

```
<asp:GridView ID="RegistrantsView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                 AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                 CellPadding="4" 
                 ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                 <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                 <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                 <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                 <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                 <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                 <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                 <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                 <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                 <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                 <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
             </asp:GridView>
```

C#:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FFL-New DataConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connection.Open();//opens connection on page load
    SqlCommand selectAllCommand = new SqlCommand();
    selectAllCommand.CommandText = "select * from registrants";
    selectAllCommand.Connection = connection;

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    sda.SelectCommand = selectAllCommand;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    RegistrantsView.DataSource = dt;
    RegistrantsView.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should note that your query is prone to [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) this is a **Security Risk**!!

Instead of ExecuteNonQuery use a DataAdapter and fill a DataTable, then set the DataSource for the RegistrantsView *before* the `DataBind`:

```
protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchBoxValue = SearchBox.Text;
    string columnNameValue = ColumnName.SelectedValue;
    columnNameValue.ToLower();

    string sqlQuery = "select * from registrants";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (SqlCommand searchCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
              dt.Load(reader);
        }
    }

    RegistrantsView.DataSource = dt;
    RegistrantsView.DataBind();
}
```

And if it's in the PageLoad:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostback)
    {
        string sqlQuery = "select * from registrants";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FFL-New DataConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand searchCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                      dt.Load(reader);
                }
            }
        }
        RegistrantsView.DataSource = dt;
        RegistrantsView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will use a parameterized query and I understand why now. But I have another question now. I am still using a search box to grab the input from the user. Will I still be open to SQL injections from this? Should I just get rid of the search box feature?

Comment: @stewbydoo - Don't get rid of the search box feature, just don't use `"select * ... where myColumn = " + searchTextBox.Text`   Use **[parameters](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)** instead

Comment: tried this and it leads to an error where the DataSource and the DataSource ID are both being called thus it tells me to use one or the other.

Comment: Does this have to do with the Parameters or with your *original* question?

Comment: It has to do with the answer to your question. I tried changing the RegistrantsView.DataSource to dt and it gave me the error.

Comment: In your .aspx file, make sure the RegistrantsView dosn't have a DataSourceId attribute

Comment: I removed it and now it works but nothing comes up at all. Above is what I really want to do. I reformatted the question.